# java redirect 301

Tags: java

Preciso fazer um direcionamento permanente via servlet no java, com o código abaixo:

Aqui ele direciona com o status 301

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
response.setHeader("Location", "https://google.com.br");
```

Aqui ele direciona com o status 200

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
response.setHeader("Location", "https://www.google.com.br");
```

Alguém sabe porque não tem o mesmo comportamento? Estou tendo problemas para direcionar para outros domínios, onde os mesmos sempre ficam com status 200.